# Count number of items of an array exist in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have an array `A` and a set of arrays in `B`. What's the fast way to find how many items in `A` exist in each row of `B`? For example, if I have:

```
A = np.array([2, 5, 10])
B = np.array([(3, 5, 10), (1, 2, 5), (4, 6, 9)])
```

So I should get `C = [2, 2, 0]`.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `[2,2,0]`?

Answer (score 2):

`np.count_nonzero(np.isin(B, A), axis=1)` might be a way of achieving the result you look for. Or, in a more elegant way - as of by suggestion of @mozway - `np.isin(B, A).sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: `np.isin(B, A).sum(1)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use broadcasting:

```
(B==A[:,None,None]).sum((0,2))
```

Output:

```
array([2, 2, 0])
```